# Return array of counts for each feature of input

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of integer labels and I would like to determine how many of each label is present and store those values in an array of the same size as the input.
This can be accomplished with the following loop:

```
def counter(labels):
    sizes = numpy.zeros(labels.shape)
    for num in numpy.unique(labels):
        mask = labels == num
        sizes[mask] = numpy.count_nonzero(mask)
return sizes
```

with input:

```
array = numpy.array([
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 1, 3],
       [3, 1, 3, 1]])
```

`counter()` returns:

```
array([[ 2.,  5.,  1.,  4.],
       [ 2.,  5.,  5.,  4.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  4.,  5.]])
```

However, for large arrays, with many unique labels, 60,000 in my case, this takes a considerable amount time. This is the first step in a complex algorithm and I can't afford to spend more than about 30 seconds on this step. Is there a function that already exists that can accomplish this? If not, how can I speed up the existing loop?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] with a sample input and output? Why doesn't `np.unique` work for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Here's one using [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) -

```
_, tags, count = np.unique(labels, return_counts=1, return_inverse=1)
sizes = count[tags]
```

**Approach #2**

With positive numbers in `labels`, simpler and more efficient way with [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) -

```
sizes = np.bincount(labels)[labels]
```

---

**Runtime test**

Setup with `60,000` unique positive numbers and two such sets of lengths `100,000` and `1000,000` are timed.

Set #1 :

```
In [192]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: labels = np.random.randint(0,60000,(100000))

In [193]: %%timeit
     ...: sizes = np.zeros(labels.shape)
     ...: for num in np.unique(labels):
     ...:     mask = labels == num
     ...:     sizes[mask] = np.count_nonzero(mask)
1 loop, best of 3: 2.32 s per loop

In [194]: %timeit np.bincount(labels)[labels]
1000 loops, best of 3: 376 µs per loop

In [195]: 2320/0.376 # Speedup figure
Out[195]: 6170.212765957447
```

Set #2 :

```
In [196]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: labels = np.random.randint(0,60000,(1000000))

In [197]: %%timeit
     ...: sizes = np.zeros(labels.shape)
     ...: for num in np.unique(labels):
     ...:     mask = labels == num
     ...:     sizes[mask] = np.count_nonzero(mask)
1 loop, best of 3: 43.6 s per loop

In [198]: %timeit np.bincount(labels)[labels]
100 loops, best of 3: 5.15 ms per loop

In [199]: 43600/5.15 # Speedup figure
Out[199]: 8466.019417475727
```

Comment: Happy new year!!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ You too, soon will be hopefully at your place!